# Retrofitting cruise control into a Jeep Cherokee XJ 1999?

Tags: jeep, cruise-control, cherokee

Found a GREAT deal on a Jeep Cherokee 1999. But it doesn't have cruise control. what is involved in retrofitting a cruise control system into it?

If you paid to have it done, what did it cost you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the kit cost but I helped a friend fit an aftermarket kit to a Renault Espace.

It took depression from the intake manifold to control the throttle quadrant via a diaphragm chamber.

Then there was the on/set/rest switch and control box which is the easy part once the switch has been located sensibly.

This was a kit available for just about any car / van.

Comment: I don't see why French cars would ever need this - isn't the average French driver's version of cruise control just "keep the gas pedal flat on the floor"? ;)

Comment: @alephzero It's the Italians with Binary throttle disease... The French police and speed cameras on the autoroutes are much less forgiving now...

Answer (score 0):

Had a cruise control aftermarket system in a Nissan D-22 2.5L TDI. It was mechanical and used a cable to open the intake manifold. It had a sensor to disconnect when touching the clutch or brake. It would also disconnect if the engine was forced, like going on 5th gear on a steep climb, altough I don't think this was feature of the thingy I did like it.

The price for the installation should be around US$250 in my opinion, you don't wan't to go cheap here. The kit I don't really know, because we pay "My country" prices around here but on ebay the one I had [THIS CRUISE CONTROL](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rostra-250-1223-Universal-Cruise-Control-Kit-250-3742-Lighted-Stalk-Relay-/261094381290) is on the US$200 price point.